# Methods to update data in multiple Classes and Data tables

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net coming more from a database background and am working on a project that contains classes that have methods to update data in a database. Everything works great until I need to process an update on the database side that uses more than one class. What is the best way to set properties for multiple classes and then be able to update the database on the back end?

Simplified Example:

Class 1

property a,
property b,
property c

Update Method for a, b, c

End Class

Class 2

property d,
property e,
property f

Update Method for d, e, f

End Class

On the database, a, b, c, d, e, f need to be updated in one stored procedure so we can rollback if there is an error on the update.

I looked into vb.net inheritance but my understanding is that a base class cannot be inherited by more than one sub class, which I would need to do in the real application so that won't work.

Sorry if this is unclear, as I said, I'm new to this and just trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this update on the vb side.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably put the update code elsewhere in, say, a centralized domain manager class, and have the update method take as arguments both instances -- class 1 and class 2.  This is only because you said you have a stored procedure which deals with data from both entities.

In the future, for more-straightforward cases, I would definitely suggest checking out the .NET entity framework.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment. As a followup, what would be the best practice for this new centralized class: 1. inherit all classes that will be used in the new class then or 2. Just create the new class with properties that will be used in the update? I'm just trying to minimize the mess at this point. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you can only inherit one base class.  And I think you misunderstood my answer.  I wasn't suggesting you inherit anything; I was suggesting you create a shared (i.e. static) class that has an update method which takes an instance of class 1 and an instance of class 2 and calls the stored procedure with data from both.